# I want to understand the time and space complexity of my program

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science, anagram

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
CHARACTER_HASH = dict(zip(letters, [0]*len(letters)))

def mapLettersToHash(text_a):
  for char in text_a:
    if char in CHARACTER_HASH.keys():
      CHARACTER_HASH[char]+=1

def computeCommonLetters(text_b):
  common_letters = 0    
  for char in text_b:
    if CHARACTER_HASH[char] > 0:
      common_letters+=1
  return common_letters

def computeUncommonLetters(text_a, text_b, common_letters):
  return len(text_a)+len(text_b)-(2*common_letters)

text_1 = "hello"
text_2 = "billion"

mapLettersToHash(text_1)
common = computeCommonLetters(text_2)
result = computeUncommonLetters(text_1, text_2, common)
print(result)
```

**Problem**: Two strings of sizes m and n are given, we have to find how many characters need to be removed from both the string so that they become anagrams of each other

I am trying to compute the space and time complexity of my program.
As per my deduction:

1. Creating a character hash takes constant time and space
2. Next, mapping characters of text_a(if size is m) will take `O(m)` time
3. Next, computing common characters from text_b(if size is n) will take `O(n)` time
4. Computing the uncommon characters is a simple arithmetic operation, hence will take constant time.

Therefore, my final program will have:

**Time complexity**: O(m+n)

**Space complexity**: O(1) {because of CHARACTER_HASH}

Please let me know if I have missed something? Thanks

Comment: space complexity is `O(m)` since the `CHARACTER_HASH` maintains a key for each char in `m`

Comment: Thanks @gidim for responding, I would like to know what about the `computeCommonLetters`, will it not add to the total time complexity?

Comment: Not in big-O sense, since all the operations in `computeCommonLetters`are O(1).  (Given that we allow addition and multiplication to be considered O(1), they are not really, since they will take longer time for bigger values.)

Comment: I would like to add another comment; your code is not working properly. What happens if you compare the strings `'a'` and `'aaa'` for example? You must reduce the hash count once a hash is found in the second string.

Comment: Yes , understood. I will add `abs()` to compute the absolute difference then.Thank you sharing your thoughts on this and correcting me !

Comment: `abs()` is not likely to help you, is it? Would it not be easier just to add `CHARACTER_HASH[char] -= 1` directly after `common_letters += 1`?